# How to prompt the user to unlock the lockscreen, when he/she click on the lockscreen widget?

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen

I have made one widget which basically shows the Rss-feed from a site. When it is clicked upon, it opens the respective link. All is good upto here.

Now when I place it on lockscreen, it responds exactly same like it is on homescreen. I want that when user clicks on the widget, it prompts user to first unlock the screen and then open the browser. How do I achieve this? Help is appreciated. Please let me know if any more information is required. Thanks.